# Perl improve performance of generating 1 pixel image

Tags: perl, nginx

Hi I need to generate a 1x1 pixel image in perl, what can be the fastest way to generate this. Assuming i will be getting 10K connections/per second on my web server.

Currently i am using this :

```
print MIME::Base64::decode("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABAQMAAAAl21bKAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAZQTFRF////AAAAVcLTfgAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAABYktHRACIBR1IAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAB3RJTUUH0gQCEx05cqKA8gAAAApJREFUeJxjYAAAAAIAAUivpHEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

I cannot host a static file, as we need to process the request for some data.

Thanks
Kathiresh Nadar

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_empty_gif_module.html

Comment: Have you found that your code is too slow, profiled it, and found that this is a bottleneck?

Comment: *"I cannot host a static file, as we need to process the request for some data"* Are you saying that the contents of the pixel depends on parameters from an HTTP request?

Answer (score 2):

First off, for high performance perl you should be using fastcgi (via the `FCGI` module directly, or the `CGI::Fast` wrapper) or mod-perl or some other technology to make your script stick around as a persistent process in memory.

Secondly, if you're processing the request for some other data first and that involves anything like writing to a file or talking to a database or something like that, your time will be dominated by that processing. Generating the image is not the slow part.

But let's answer your question anyway: assuming that you are using some keep-the-script-in-memory technology, then the first thing you can do is move your `MIME::Base64::decode` call to a `BEGIN` block, store the result in a variable, and use that variable.

But also, sending the image over the wire is likely going to take longer than the processing on the server, so why are you sending 167 bytes of PNG when you could be sending 42 bytes of GIF? Put both of those pieces of advice together, and you get:

```
my $gifdata;
BEGIN { $gifdata = MIME::Base64::decode(
            "R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"); }
print $gifdata;
```

Comment: *"why are you sending 167 bytes of PNG when you could be sending 42 bytes of GIF?"* Perhaps because the time taken to transmit 125 bytes of data should be insignificant? That is probably smaller than the associated HTTP stuff